# WSAD to SQL Server Connectivity Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc, wsad5.1

I am facing issues connecting to SQL Server 2008 from WSAD  5.1.2  ( WAS version 1.5.1.1 ).
I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver Version 1.2 on JRE 1.4.2 for the same as Driver Version 2.0 for SQL Server 2008 is not compatible on JRE 1.4.2.
The database connection is being established but while retrieving the data I get an exception

> java.sql.SQLException: [IBM][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 1 (""): Data type 0x38 is unknown.”

Any help to resolve this issue is highly appreciated also any suggestions/alternate ways on connecting to SQL Server 2008 from WAS 1.5.1.1 is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was resolved using JDBC 1.2 drivers which run on jdk 1.4

Comment: Glad you solved it :) You should however set this answer to accepted. Click the big white checkmark on the left hand side so that it becomes green.